# Resharper: Do not expand var for Tuples

Tags: c#, resharper

I have Resharper expanding (converting to explicit type) "var" when type is not evident. But it also expands "var" for long Tuples, like

```
var value = CallTuple();
```

becomes

```
(int valueA, string valueB, string valueC) value = CallTuple();
```

Is it possible to stop such conversion only for Tuples, leaving it for other types?

So

```
var intValue = CallInt();
```

becomes

```
int intValue = CallInt();
```

while

```
var value = CallTuple();
```

remains the same

```
var value = CallTuple();
```

Comment: I'm curious why you want to exclude tuples? Seems like they are the least obvious ones of all. Granted the code may look a little tidier, but is that enough?

Comment: @DavidG, when you change a name of a Tuple part in the returning method (sub-method), this change is not forced in the calling method, which requires extra manual sync effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, basically not.
 Resharper and Rider only allow differentiation between builtin and simple types and for everywhere else. Differentiation for specific types e.g. `Tuple<>` is not possible